# Can't read POST values in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem and just can't figure out what's the issue:
In my php code I can't read any of the values included in the post request.

Even if I reduce the PHP-code to just reading the value, there comes a 500 error as response.

I inspected the POST-header: all the data is sent, so you should have access in php.

Here's the code:

```
$('#contactForm').submit(function (e) {

e.preventDefault();
var $form = $(this);

// check if the input is valid
if (!$form.valid()) return false;



$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'contact.php',
    data: $('#contactForm').serialize(),

    success: function (response) {
        $(".formSuccess").show();
        $(".formError").hide();

    },
    error: function (response) {
        $(".formSuccess").hide();
        $(".formError").show();

    }
});
```

});

```
contact.php

    <?php
$empfaenger = "info@heitech.co.at";
$betreff = "Formularnachricht";
$text = "Formularnachricht: \n\n";
if(isset($_POST["name1"]))
{
  $text .= "Name: ".&_POST["name1"];
}
if(isset($_POST["email1"]))
{
  $text .= "\n\nEmail: ".&_POST["email1"];
}
if(isset($_POST["message1"]))
{
  $text .= "\n\nNachricht: ".&_POST["message1"];
}

//$text = wordwrap($text, 70); 
mail($empfaenger, $betreff, $text);
?>
```

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: You write &_POST instead of $_POST....

Comment: Where's the form?

Comment: If you inspected the POST _header_ and saw your data there, then it's not POST data. POST data goes in the request _body_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `&_POST` -> `$_POST`.

Comment: Thanks alot... can't believe I didn't see.